Ouroboros capacitor?
The ouroboros is a snake eating its own tail. If we think of the top surface of the snake as being one plate of a capacitor, and the belly of the snake as being the other, what would happen to the charges and electric field formed between the two coiled plates? Would the "stacking" effect of each concentric spiral plate cause the electric field in the central cavity between the positive and negative plates to increase, much like how in a solenoid, each turn of wire compounds the magnetic field strength? If an input voltage is fed in through the upper and lower "jaws" of the snake, and the output is taken from the "tail" end of the coil, would this form a sort of DC transformer? 

Thank you all for your replies!  I suppose the crux of the matter is this: does a parallel-plate capacitor with multiple stacked positive and negative plates have a stronger electric field than a capacitor with a single set of plates? Do the outer sets of plates affect the field in the central gap, or do the innermost plates shield out their field contributions completely?

Assuming every outer skin is a conductor with dielectric or insulation on the other side with the two sides isolated, the construction of one loop is possible.  The polarization is formed between the top and bottom layers.
Since the construction, leaves parallel top skins and bottom skins, there is no increase in capacitance with this effect. In fact the capacitance reduces proportional to the %age of length that is split with a full loop resulting in only 50% of the initial value.
The parallel conductors also reduce L by the same ratio of L/C so the impedance at self resonant  frequency will be the same while the SRF doubles for one loop.
Does this propose an interesting opportunity for reactors?  I doubt it. Maybe you can think of a good example.

That snake reminded me of Mobius-ring transmission line oscillator.

You're tricking yourself by thinking of a snake.
Remember that the charges on a capacitor plates are only there because there's the opposite charge on the plate right next to that.
So, in your snake picture, the positive charges in your snake's skull and neck? They wouldn't be there in reality, because there's no negative charges to attract them (instead, there's the positive charges in the snake's throat to repel them!).
Same for the negative charges in your snake's jaw and chin: nope; they wouldn't be there in reality, because there's no positive charges to get and keep them there; instead, their negative neighbors repel them.
So, your snake would have exactly one "snake turn" of capacitor (namely, where the "colon" of your snake is not filled with self-shielding snake itself), and the rest would just be a very long conductor with no use for the capacitance.

No, assuming the terminal conductors are metal and the positive side is equipotential and the negative side is equipotential.
There will only be an electric field between positive and negative terminals, so if you twist a capacitor so that you insert one end into the capacitor, there will be less length where there is electric field between positive and negative terminals.


Would the "stacking" effect of each concentric spiral plate cause the electric field in the central cavity between the positive and negative plates to increas

No but it would increase eveywhere due to the shielding effect (which reduces the usable plate area, and that reduces the capacitance).
Probably the best approach is to look at this like a variable capacitor, as the snake capacitor reduces in usable plate area the capacitance goes down so by the capacitor law the potential (voltage) is going to go up.
